# Google API for Admin console exists?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

I need to check programmaticaly if in admin console setting ON or OFF.
For example:

```
1. Log in to admin.google.com as an administrator.
2. Select Apps.
3. Select Google Workspace.
4. Select Gmail.
5. Under Safety - Spoofing and authentication, check - Protect against spoofing of employee names.
```

But I didn't find this Google API.
Maybe someone know is this API exist?

I alreday checked this Google API:
[https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest](https://stackoverflow.com)

[https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/apis](https://stackoverflow.com)

[https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Kindly correct me if I'm wrong with my understanding of your question. You'd like to be able to check through APIs the options that are enabled or disabled in your Google Admin console. Would that be correct?

Comment: @Saddles Yes, absolutely correct

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. To answer your question, as far as I know, there's currently no API to check all the settings of your Admin console at the moment, and I believe the closest thing that's related to this is the Admin Settings API. You may try checking it out. However, from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings), it was deprecated on October 31, 2018, where it states that `They were sunset on October 31, 2018 and are no longer available.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I didn't find direct API to check ACTUAL STATE of admin console settings, but I used Method: **reports.activities.list** which allows you to check CHANGES OF STATE for settings.
Here you can play with Google API [TRY ME](https://developers.google.com/workspace/explore?filter=&discoveryUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fadmin.googleapis.com%2F%24discovery%2Frest%3Fversion%3Dreports_v1&discoveryRef=resources.activities.methods.list&operationId=reports.activities.list) where userKey - admin email, applicationName - admin.

Java Usage:

```
`public Activities getAdminConsoleActivities(String rootEmail,
                                            ServiceAccountCredentials apiToken,
                                            GsuiteEventName eventName,
                                            String nextPageToken,
                                            LocalDateTime startTime) {
    Reports service = getReportsService(apiToken);
    return new GsuiteBackoffExecutor<Activities>(apiToken)
            .get(() -> service.activities()
                    .list("all", "admin")
                    .setEventName(eventName.name())
                    .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                    .setMaxResults(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
                    .setStartTime(startTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(YYYY_MM_DD_T_HH_MM_SS_SSS_Z)))
                    .setQuotaUser(rootEmail)
                    .execute());
}`
```

Event Names you can find  [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/admin-application-settings)